# Relation with query JPA - Spring

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need you help. I need to create a service with Spring, which return a relation but a query specific.
Example:

```
{
    "fecha": "2016-01-04 00:00:00",
    "fechaInicio": "1704",
    "fechaFin": "1705",
    "Participantes":[{ //THIS IS THE RELATION
      "id":1234
      "name":Robert
    }]
},
```

But the relation "Participantes" has query specific. Just not is OneToMany, I need to create WHERE in "Participantes" like:

```
SELECT id, name FROM Participantes WHERE tableA.id = sfrstcr_pidm
       AND SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE IN ('RE', 'RW')
       AND sfrstcr_crn = '10027'
       AND sfrstcr_term_code = '202015';
```

How I do? Thank u for u attention.